# XAMPP- MySQL shutdown unexpectedly and i dont know why

Tags: mariadb, xampp

Cant really find the problem in error.log ,but when i start XAMPP and MySQL loads, it crashes instantly

```
2024-03-11 13:59:37 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision  c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 22968
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB.   Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 6479686; transaction id 15094
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from     C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-03-11 13:59:38 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: there is no shutdown in your error log only a running mariadb server

Comment: Thats the thing so how can i know whats wrong?

Comment: xampp has its own error log, that would be a good start and usually the server would keepo the last message or have more files with he error log

Comment: Please post the last 300 lines of your error log from the TAIL.